# Insert new records only into SQL Table Using VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms, vba

I have an Excel workbook with the below code -

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim iRowNo As Integer
    Dim sFirstName, sLastName As String

    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        'Open a connection to SQL Server
        conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
            "Data Source=server1;" & _
            "Initial Catalog=table1;" & _
            "User ID=user1; Password=pass1"

        'Skip the header row
        iRowNo = 2

        'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
        Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
            sFirstName = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
            sLastName = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)

            'Generate and execute sql statement
            ' to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
            conn.Execute "Insert into dbo.Customers (FirstName, LastName) " & _
                         "values ('" & sFirstName & "', '" & sLastName & "')"

            iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
        Loop

        MsgBox "Customers imported."

        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing

    End With

End Sub
```

This opens up a connection to my database and inputs the values from the stated columns.

The primary key is an incremental key on the database.  The problem is it will copy ALL values.

I'd like to add new rows of data into the Excel Sheet and only insert those rows that don't already exist.

I've tried different methods ('merge', 'if exist', if not exist', etc.) but I can't get it right.

The solution has to be through VBA.  Setting up a link using SSMS is not an option.

I understand that it may be possible to use temporary tables and then trigger a procedure which performs the merge but I want to look into that as a last resort.  Haven't read up on it yet (making my way through my MS SQL bible book) but I'm hoping it won't be necessary.

---Update from @Kannan's answer---

New portion of VBA -

```vb
conn.Execute "IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Customers WHERE FirstName = '" &      sFirstName & "' and LastName = '" & sLastName & "') " & _
             "THEN UPDATE dbo.customers SET WHERE Firstname = '" & sFirstName & "' and LastName = '" & sLastName & "' " & _
             "ELSE INSERT INTO dbo.Customers (FirstName, LastName) " & _
             "VALUES ('" & sFirstName & "', '" & sLastName & "')"
```

This returns error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your SQL query isn't quite right - there is no `THEN` in a SQL `IF`.

Also, you don't need to do anything if it does exist, so just use if not exists.

```
"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Customers WHERE FirstName = '" & sFirstName & "' and LastName = '" & sLastName & "') " & _
         "INSERT INTO dbo.Customers (FirstName, LastName) " & _
         "VALUES ('" & sFirstName & "', '" & sLastName & "')"
```

Comment: That's spot on.  Thankyou BeanFrog.  I had actually tried IF NOT EXISTS before, but I obviously didn't get it right.  I certainly didn't use the 'Select 1' part.  Could you tell me how the SELECT 1 works?

Comment: It's just a regular select statement, but instead of any columns, you select the number 1. All this does is to prevent the overhead of getting all the column details, when all you need to know is 'does this row exist' rather than 'what is in this row'.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks again.  This is going to set me up nicely once  finally start working on SQL exclusively.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it for you.

```
Sub Button_Click()
'TRUSTED CONNECTION
    On Error GoTo errH

    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim intImportRow As Integer
    Dim strFirstName, strLastName As String

    Dim server, username, password, table, database As String


    With Sheets("Sheet1")

            server = .TextBox1.Text
            table = .TextBox4.Text
            database = .TextBox5.Text


            If con.State <> 1 Then

                con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & server & ";Initial Catalog=" & database & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;"
                'con.Open

            End If
            'this is the TRUSTED connection string

            Set rs.ActiveConnection = con

            'delete all records first if checkbox checked
            If .CheckBox1 Then
                con.Execute "delete from tbl_demo"
            End If

            'set first row with records to import
            'you could also just loop thru a range if you want.
            intImportRow = 10

            Do Until .Cells(intImportRow, 1) = ""
                strFirstName = .Cells(intImportRow, 1)
                strLastName = .Cells(intImportRow, 2)

                'insert row into database
                con.Execute "insert into tbl_demo (firstname, lastname) values ('" & strFirstName & "', '" & strLastName & "')"

                intImportRow = intImportRow + 1
            Loop

            MsgBox "Done importing", vbInformation

            con.Close
            Set con = Nothing

    End With

Exit Sub

errH:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Add a reference to:
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library

FYI, my sheet looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql query like this:

```
IF Exists ( Select 1 from dbo.customers where Firstname = '" & sFirstName & "' and LastName = '" & sLastName & "' THEN Update dbo.customers set --other columns where Firstname = '" & sFirstName & "' and LastName = '" & sLastName & "'
ELSE Insert into dbo.Customers (FirstName, LastName) " & _
                     "values ('" & sFirstName & "', '" & sLastName & "')"
```

Not sure about the syntax for excel and C#, you can correct that similar to this query

Comment: hi @Kannan, I've added this into my code and updated my question.  Do you know why I may be getting the error that I mentioned.  It looks like you missed a closing bracket in your first line.  I think I added it in the right place.

Comment: Also, I wasn't too sure how to input the set command.  I assume "--other columns" was the commented section?  So I took that out.