# MS Excel: using Shell in VBA to run an SSIS package as an embedded object in a worksheet

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, powerquery

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**
I want to upload an Excel table to a SQL Server database table by pushing a button tied to a VBA macro.

I want the macro to wait for the process to complete before continuing.

**My current method:**
Currently, I have an SSIS package embedded as an object in a cell behind the button tied to the macro.  My macro is pretty rough at this stage because I'm still trying to figure out how to run the SSIS package without it opening in the default app.

I want it to run in the background via a shell script.  The macro would wait for a signal from the shell script saying that the upload was successful before continuing.  I had this running previously with the SSIS package as an external file and ran the shell (which worked); but, I really want it to be contained inside the Excel file.

**My code:**

```
Sub UpdateGroupsMacro()
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Object 1")).Select
Selection.Verb Verb:=Activate
' Shell ("DTEXEC.EXE /F " & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & "\xl\embeddings\oleObject1.bin""") <---This wasn't working even when I went one level deeper.
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Worksheets("Macro").ListObjects("GetGroupsTableCount").Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm really not trying to just stump the community here.

Ideally, I'd just have a PowerQuery to Insert into [databaseServer].[schema].[MyTable] from Select (ActiveWorkbook.FullName & Range("My Data Table").  But alas, it couldn't be that easy.

Comment: Just checking back.  Bueller?  Bueller? ...Bueller?  ...

Comment: Couple questions.  Are you trying to load data from the same excel document you are attempting to run the package from?  and what is "ActiveWorkbook.FullName" in your shell command?

Comment: When you open an Excel document, you're actually working from a copy.  The file on the hard drive doesn't actually update or change - it just gets replaced by the copy you're working on when you save it.  So, once it's saved, other apps can also open a copy and access the updated info in it.  

I'm making changes/updates to a table in a worksheet and then am updating that set in the database.  So, you'll note at the beginning, the workbook is saved so that the SSIS package can have access to the updated values in the table.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking you would run into that issue when SSIS tried to access the excel file you currently have open, but you wouldn't.    Executing SSIS via command line and using DTEXEC.EXE, it needs the path to the .dtsx file to execute, with it embedded in the excel I don't think that would work.   I think the only way to get around that would be in the macro, basically temporarily export the embedded object, then run DTEXEC.EXE passing it that temp location/file and then delete it when it's done.

Comment: Thanks.  I think that will work.  I'll give it a shot.

I was sort of hoping for someone to say, "Why are you doing it the hard way?  Why don't you...?"

Comment: Not sure if you explored this, but you could just connect to sql via the vba and insert/update as opposed to a SSIS package.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293669/insert-new-records-only-into-sql-table-using-vba  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627480/i-need-to-insert-data-into-sql-server-from-excel-using-vba