# Using Excel as a frontend to an Azure SQL Database - How to write data from Excel to Database

Tags: excel, azure-sql-database

I am thinking about using Excel as a Front-End to an Azure SQL Database.

While retrieving data from the database to Excel is fairly easy, I am struggeling to find the best way to write data from Excel back to the database.

I have found an Excel Add-In called "SQL Spreads" that seems to help with writing back from Excel to the database but it is quiet expensive.

Is it possible to do the "writing back" with VBA or Python (e.g. via xlwings and SQLAlchemy)?

Is there anybody out there who has already done something like this and can share his/her experience?

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: You can definitely use VBA to write to Azure SQL (or any database). The hard part is the authentication. There are many online examples that you could try. I repeat my comment from below: why on earth would you use Python when you can do it in VBA (which for example means you can add a nice form or do the data update via a button)

Comment: Dear Nick, thanks a lot for your feedback. I was thinking about Python simply because I have no experience in VBA. But I understand that VBA might be a better choice because VBA is better "integrated" into Excel. Can you provide me with further information/links to the respective online examples?

Comment: This was the third link when I googled it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293669/insert-new-records-only-into-sql-table-using-vba The code in the question should get you some way towards a solution. Once you've tried it and have a specific issue you can ask a question. I do suggest that you take the time to learn the VBA approach because there are _so_ many Python programmers with zero experience with other languages.

Comment: I guess you could use Python if you really wanted https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/introducing-python-in-excel-the-best-of-both-worlds-for-data/ba-p/3905482

Answer (score 0):

You can use below process to write data from excel file to SQL database using python:
**Step1:**
Connect Azure SQL database using below code :

```
server = '<serverName>.database.windows.net'
database = '<databaseName>'
user = '<userName>'
password = '<Password>'
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

conn_str = (
    f"DRIVER={{{driver}}};"
    f"SERVER={server};"
    f"DATABASE={database};"
    f"UID={user};"
    f"PWD={password}"
)
conn_str_encoded = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn_str)

try:
    engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={conn_str_encoded}", fast_executemany=True)
    print("Passed")
except:
    print("Failed!")
```

**Step2:**
Create a data frame by reading the excel from the path using below code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('<filepath>', engine='openpyxl')
```

Write data frame into SQL database using below code:

```
df.to_sql('samp', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

**Complete code:**

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

server = '<serverNmae>.database.windows.net'
database = '<dbName>'
user = '<userName>'
password = '<password>'
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

conn_str = (
    f"DRIVER={{{driver}}};"
    f"SERVER={server};"
    f"DATABASE={database};"
    f"UID={user};"
    f"PWD={password}"
)
conn_str_encoded = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn_str)
try:
    engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={conn_str_encoded}", fast_executemany=True)
    print("Passed")
except:
    print("Failed!")

df = pd.read_excel('<excelFilePath>', engine='openpyxl')

df.to_sql('samp', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
print("Saved in the table")
print(df)
```

You can get the output as mentioned below after executing above code:

[image]

**Output from SQL database:**

[image]

Comment: Why use python when you can use VBA and all of the associated excel integrations?